# MongoDb replica set: How long in STARTUP status?

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

I setup up a 3 server MongoDb replica set about 2 days ago. It's geo-located so there is some space between the VPS's, but rs.status() on the PRIMARY shows the other 2 servers have been in STARTUP status for nearly two days. There is very little data. Maybe a few MBs, that's all. How long should it normally take before they move into STARTUP2?

Comment: Probably there would be some issue with replica set configuration. checkout `rs.conf()`

Comment: Have you set up a lot of replica sets? How long did it take for them to all sync up?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. Belongs to http://dba.stackexchange.com SO is primarily about problems with code (the one you have written).

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus for your help, but I'd like to vote against your vote to close. I tried dba.stackexchange.com and it's a ghost town. If SO is not the place for MongoDb questions why are there at least 28 different MongoDb tags with nearly 10 thousand Q/As?